# ffmpeg - 2 Files - Convert ->Concate->Watermark not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, concatenation, converters

I am currently trying to bulk add outros and watermarks to my videos.
I am new to this.

This is my code for converting the videos into the same format

```
cd source

for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%f" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1500k -s 720x720 -crf 22 -g 1 -keyint_min 1 -preset slow -shortest -ar 44100 "../converted/c_%%f"
)

cd outro
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%f" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1500k -s 720x720 -crf 22 -g 1 -keyint_min 1 -preset slow -shortest -ar 44100 "../../converted/outro/c_%%f"
)
call concat.bat
pause
```

This is the code I use then to concat the files:

```
cd converted   
   for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
      echo.>%%f.list
      echo file '%%f' >> %%f.list
      echo file 'c_outro.mp4' >> %%f.list
    )


for %%f in (*.list) do (
  ffmpeg -f concat -i %%f -c copy concatenated/%%f.mp4
) 
call final.bat
pause
```

This is the code I use to add the watermark:

```
    cd concatenated 
for %%f in (*.list) do 
    ffmpeg -i "%%f" -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" "../../final_%%f"
) 

pause
```

Where did I do the mistake ? It is converting the videos without problem and concating them but watermarking them seems not to work. Please advice.

Comment: Somehow the right formating for the code is not working

Comment: You can do this all with one command and avoid additional, unnecessary encoding by using the concat filter instead of the concat demuxer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LN said, do it in one command.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i outro.mp4 -loop 1 -i logo.png
 -filter_complex "[0]scale=720:720,setsar=1[m];[1]scale=720:720,setsar=1[o];
                  [m][0:a][o][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a];[v][2]overlay=10:10:shortest=1[vid]"
 -c:v libx264 -ar 44100 -map [vid] -map [a] "../converted/final_%%f"
```

Of course, you will have to iterate through the source videos, like in the Q:

```
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
       ffmpeg -i "%%f" -i outro.mp4 -loop 1 -i logo.png
     -filter_complex "[0]scale=720:720,setsar=1[m];[1]scale=720:720,setsar=1[o];
                      [m][0:a][o][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a];[v][2]overlay=10:10:shortest=1[vid]"
     -c:v libx264 -ar 44100 -map [vid] -map [a] "../converted/final_%%f"
)
```

It's best to convert the outro once to match the source video properties:

```
ffmpeg -i outro.mp4 -vf scale=720:720,setsar=1 -ar 44100 -g 1 outro-new.mp4
```

If you do this, skip the `[1]scale=720:720,setsar=1[o];` and replace `[o]` with `[1:v]`

Comment: Wow, everything in one comand that is impressive. I only understand that code partly. Will look into it more to be able to create such commands myself. Thank you!
the outro is always the same and in the outro folder.
Only the source video will change everytime.
With this new code I am not sure how to make it use a new source video everytime, please advice.

Comment: Furthermore I get this error when just trying it with one file: http://i.imgur.com/1OOvotM.png

Comment: Oops. forgot the audio feed to the concat. Will correct that. Your outro properties are different. Best to convert it once, and use that file.

Comment: Will convert the outro once, that saves time.
Now I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/lo22pvf.png 
Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: Once converted, you should input `outro-new.mp4`, not `outro.mp4`. You are executing from within bin, so remove `../` from `../converted/final_%%f`

Comment: Oh that was my bad. Didn't realized that.
I still get one error: http://i.imgur.com/JYAcgge.png
Sorry for asking that much but i am currently not really advanced in ffmpeg, need to read more into it after this.

Comment: Perfect it is working now, thank you for your help and patience!